# How to reference inline svg as cursor in css style?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

how to reference an inline svg as cursor?

In the code attach, first cursor declaration "cursor:pointer"  an second (png) works without problems.

Third declaration doesn't work for me. What I'm doing wrong?. Only need a working sample
Thanks in advance

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<svg version='1.1' id='project' xmlns:svg='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
                                xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
                                xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'
>
<script type='text/ecmascript'>

<style>

.boton
{
    /*cursor:pointer
    cursor: url(data:image/png;base64,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), auto;);
    */
    cursor: url(data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg fill="%23FF0000" height="48" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="48" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M20 11H7.83l5.59-5.59L12 4l-8 8 8 8 1.41-1.41L7.83 13H20v-2z"/></svg>), auto;);
}

</style>
</script>

<g id="toggleInsertaElementoLS" class="boton" toggleButton="true" triStateButton="false">   
            <path id="bordeLS" fill="url(#rellenoBotonesInsercion)" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
                M6.875,282.375h46c1.104,0,2,0.895,2,2v21c0,1.104-0.896,2-2,2h-46c-1.104,0-2-0.896-2-2v-21
                C4.875,283.27,5.771,282.375,6.875,282.375z"/>
            <g id="dibujoLS">
                <path fill="#660000" stroke="#660000" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="3" d="
                M22.46,296.273v-9.67h1.28v8.529h4.763v1.141H22.46z"/>
                <path fill="#660000" stroke="#660000" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="3" d="
                M29.59,293.156l1.209-0.104c0.055,0.479,0.188,0.881,0.398,1.188c0.207,0.313,0.533,0.563,0.973,0.752
                c0.44,0.191,0.933,0.285,1.482,0.285c0.489,0,0.92-0.074,1.293-0.217c0.374-0.146,0.652-0.346,0.834-0.6
                c0.182-0.25,0.276-0.527,0.276-0.826c0-0.31-0.088-0.57-0.264-0.795c-0.178-0.229-0.464-0.414-0.871-0.57
                c-0.26-0.1-0.833-0.26-1.719-0.471c-0.891-0.216-1.511-0.416-1.867-0.604c-0.462-0.241-0.806-0.543-1.03-0.896
                c-0.23-0.359-0.342-0.77-0.342-1.205c0-0.49,0.138-0.943,0.417-1.371c0.275-0.422,0.679-0.748,1.213-0.965
                c0.532-0.229,1.124-0.332,1.775-0.332c0.716,0,1.349,0.117,1.897,0.346c0.548,0.232,0.967,0.57,1.264,1.021
                c0.292,0.438,0.453,0.945,0.475,1.521l-1.227,0.09c-0.064-0.604-0.288-1.063-0.667-1.383c-0.382-0.313-0.944-0.469-1.688-0.469
                c-0.772,0-1.337,0.141-1.691,0.428c-0.354,0.281-0.531,0.625-0.531,1.025c0,0.346,0.126,0.631,0.375,0.854
                c0.245,0.229,0.889,0.453,1.931,0.689c1.038,0.229,1.752,0.438,2.14,0.617c0.563,0.258,0.979,0.588,1.246,0.979
                c0.267,0.396,0.403,0.857,0.403,1.375c0,0.521-0.148,1.002-0.442,1.455s-0.716,0.813-1.269,1.063
                c-0.554,0.256-1.172,0.383-1.864,0.383c-0.876,0-1.608-0.127-2.199-0.385c-0.593-0.262-1.056-0.646-1.392-1.148
                C29.784,294.389,29.607,293.811,29.59,293.156z"/>        
                <line shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" fill="none" stroke="#2F5F9E" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="3" x1="8" y1="301.125" x2="51.75" y2="301.125"/>
            </g>
        </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works once I cleaned up the syntax a little i.e. the extraneous brackets and semicolons.

The cursor is the one you provided.

```css
.boton {
  cursor: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="%23FF0000" height="48" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="48"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M20 11H7.83l5.59-5.59L12 4l-8 8 8 8 1.41-1.41L7.83 13H20v-2z"/></svg>'), auto;
}
```

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<svg version='1.1' id='project' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
                                xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'
>

<rect class="boton" width="100%" height="100%" fill="blue"/>   
</svg>
```

Comment: Hi @Robert Longson. Sorry for my insistence. Code works in jsfiddle, but not in real browser (I tried with mozilla, IE ans Chrome)